# How I can to Parse Date in JavaScript in format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt'

Tags: javascript, parsing, datetime

I have one date in string format **"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt"**

when I try to parse, the result is **NaN**

> var test = Date.parse("15/2/2015 8:20 PM");
>
> undefined
>
> test
>
> NaN

Comment: Look at documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: read this you will get idea


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Answer (score 2):

Date expects US dates, so 2/15/2015. You can use a library like moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) to help you parsing international dates. JS does not allow this natively :(

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple to parse without a library. Just break it into parts, fix the hour based on am/pm, then pass the values to the Date constructor (remembering to subtract 1 from the month), e.g.

```js
// Parse dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt
function parseDMYHmt(s) {
  let [day, month, year, hour, minute, phase] = s.split(/\W/);
  hour = (hour%12) + (phase.toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12);
  return new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
}

["15/2/2015 8:20 AM",
 "15/2/2015 8:20 PM",
 "15/2/2015 12:00 PM",
 "15/2/2015 12:30 AM"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + ' => ' + parseDMYHmt(s).toString()));
```